# Calling stored procedure from aws Glue Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

After the ETL Job is done, What is the best way to call  stored procedure in AWS Glue script?

I am using PySpark to fetch the data from S3 and storing in staging table. After this process, need to call a stored procedure. This stored procedure loads data from the staging table into the appropriate MDS tables.

If I have to call a Stored Procedure after ETL Job is done, what is the best way? If I consider AWS lambda, is there any way that lambda can be notified after the ETL.

Comment: I'm curious to hear how you solved this? Did you end up just executing a lambda function as suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the boto sdk to fire off your lambda at the end of your glue ETL job. Since you are writing to a staging table, you will also need to have a NAT Gateway on the connection's subnet for the boto call to work. The example at this link uses boto to fire an ECS task, which would be a similar process: https://github.com/full360/glue-sneaql-demo/blob/master/Glue-Job-Script.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using py4j and all your code will be in one place, IMHO way better solution than others

[How to run arbitrary / DDL SQL statements or stored procedures using AWS Glue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775753/how-to-run-arbitrary-ddl-sql-statements-or-stored-procedures-using-aws-glue)

Answer (score 0):

Use the SDK directly avoid set up additional infrastructure and coordinate it, but some times that is not possible (network, security, architecture, etc).

In that case, you can set up a Cloudwatch Rule to trigger a Lambda when the job's status changes to SUCCEEDED.

Event pattern:

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "Glue Job State Change"
  ],
  "source": [
    "aws.glue"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "state": [
      "SUCCEEDED"
    ]
  }
}
```

and trigger a Lambda on this event.