# Calling a stored procedure in Redshift from AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

Is there an easier way than using Lambda/Boto to call a stored procedure in Redshift from AWS Glue?
I have everything setup in a Glue job and need to call a stored procedure in Redshift from the Spark script. I have a connection made to Redshift in Glue.

This question does not have the answer: [Calling stored procedure from aws Glue Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870558/calling-stored-procedure-from-aws-glue-script)

Please share any guidance on this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that using py4j and java jdbc. The best part you do not even have to install anything as Glue comes with jdbc connectors for many supported databases.
[How to run arbitrary / DDL SQL statements or stored procedures using AWS Glue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775753/how-to-run-arbitrary-ddl-sql-statements-or-stored-procedures-using-aws-glue)

Answer (score 0):

You can zip pg8000 as additional library and use it to establish connection to redshift then trigger the stored procedure.

It is not possible to trigger stored procedure from spark jdbc.